# NSLayoutConstraint activate/deactivate

Tags: swift3, nslayoutconstraint

I am simply trying to deactivate a constraint in textViewDidBeginEditing and the deactivate in textViewDidEndEditing.

My NSLayoutConstraint is an outlet.  The deactivation in textViewDidBeginEditing works, but then the reactivation on textViewDidEndEditing finds nil for the constraint.

I have tried this with both the .isActive instance value as well as the NSLayoutConstraint.activate/deactivate functions.

**The Answer**
I played around with Vasil Hristov's answer and that didn't work because he simply suggested 0 and 1000.  From Documentation:

> Priorities may not change from nonrequired to required, or from required to nonrequired. An exception will be thrown if a priority of `NSLayoutPriorityRequired` in OS X or `UILayoutPriorityRequired` in iOS is changed to a lower priority, or if a lower priority is changed to a required priority after the constraints is added to a view. Changing from one optional priority to another optional priority is allowed even after the constraint is installed on a view.

So, I had to change my priority in IB first to be something else (I chose 750 - High) and then just switched it to 250 when it wasn't needed, and created a second constraint conflicting with the first that had a 500 priority(do something else) at all times, which got me the behavior I wanted.

According to the above documentation, since High is not required, I should have been able to switch to 0, but that was still resulting in crashes so I must be reading that wrong.  Hence, why I did the second constraint thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change the priority of constraint. 
For example:

```
constraint.priority = 0;    // it's turn off
constraint.priority = 1000; // it's turn on
```

Comment: > Priorities may not change from nonrequired to required, or from required to nonrequired. An exception will be thrown if a priority of `NSLayoutPriorityRequired` in OS X or `UILayoutPriorityRequired` in iOS is changed to a lower priority, or if a lower priority is changed to a required priority after the constraints is added to a view. Changing from one optional priority to another optional priority is allowed even after the constraint is installed on a view.